# java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null from InputStreamReader

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I'm trying to parse an .obj wavefront file to be displayed with OpenGL ES, thing is, I'm getting the Nullpointer as if the file did not exist or was empty (?).
I tried two different ways of getting to parse the file, also made sure there were no empty lines on it, put it in different folders (assets, src root, res, etc...) but the result is the same. Maybe the error I'm getting is more to do with the OpenGL part of the code? But I'm kinda lost, because apparently it should work...
Also tried buffering the file outside the function, same happened. From another question here, the problem the person had, had to do with " trying to update UI from worker Thread ". Async did not help me here.

I got the code idea form this blog: http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-rendering-3d-blender-models.html

And the file to base my work on from here: https://github.com/MartianIsMe/earth-live-wallpaper/blob/d71902aa642bad0c10fc46d6839ced6e15995f7b/%20earth-live-wallpaper/SLWP/src/com/seb/SLWP/DeathStar.java

```
 fun loadObjFile() {
    try {
        var str: String
        var tmp: Array<String>
        var ftmp: Array<String>
        var v: Float
        val vlist = ArrayList<Float>()
        val nlist = ArrayList<Float>()
        val fplist = ArrayList<Fp>()
        val mContext: Context? = null
        //val inb: BufferedReader = File("androidmodel.obj").bufferedReader()
        //val inputString = inb.use { it.readText() }
        val inb = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(mContext?.getAssets()?.open
        ("src/main/res/androidmodel.obj")), 1024) //Error is here at com.example.xxx.MyGLRenderer.loadObjFile

        while (inb.readLine().also { str = it } != null) {
            tmp = str.split(" ".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
            //Parse the vertices
            if (tmp[0].equals("v", ignoreCase = true)) {
                for (i in 1..3) {
                    v = tmp[i].toFloat()
                    vlist.add(v)
                }
            }
            //Parse the vertex normals
            if (tmp[0].equals("vn", ignoreCase = true)) {
                for (i in 1..3) {
                    v = tmp[i].toFloat()
                    nlist.add(v)
                }
            }
            //Parse the faces/indices
            if (tmp[0].equals("f", ignoreCase = true)) {
                for (i in 1..3) {
                    ftmp = tmp[i].split("/".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                    val chi = ftmp[0].toInt() - 1.toLong()
                    var cht = 0
                    if (ftmp[1] != "") cht = ftmp[1].toInt() - 1
                    val chn = ftmp[2].toInt() - 1
                    fplist.add(Fp(chi, cht, chn))
                }
                NBFACES++
            }
        }
        val vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(fplist.size * 4 * 3)
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        mVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer()
        val nbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(fplist.size * 4 * 3)
        nbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        mNormBuffer = nbb.asFloatBuffer()
        for (j in fplist.indices) {
            mVertexBuffer?.put(vlist[(fplist[j].Vi * 3).toInt()])
            mVertexBuffer?.put(vlist[(fplist[j].Vi * 3 + 1).toInt()])
            mVertexBuffer?.put(vlist[(fplist[j].Vi * 3 + 2).toInt()])
            mNormBuffer?.put(nlist[fplist[j].Ni * 3])
            mNormBuffer?.put(nlist[fplist[j].Ni * 3 + 1])
            mNormBuffer?.put(nlist[fplist[j].Ni * 3 + 2])
        }
        mIndexBuffer = CharBuffer.allocate(fplist.size)
        for (j in fplist.indices) {
            mIndexBuffer?.put(j.toChar())
        }
        mVertexBuffer?.position(0)
        mNormBuffer?.position(0)
        mIndexBuffer?.position(0)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

private class Fp
(var Vi: Long, var Ti: Int, var Ni: Int)
```

Comment: What does `mContext?.getAssets()?.open("src/main/res/androidmodel.obj")` return to you?

Comment: As strange as it seems, I can't get that to log ANYWHERE. used all the log.whatever available, nothing gets logged on verbose, debug, error etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass `null` into `InputStreamReader`. The path to the asset is wrong.

- First of all the file should be located under `assets` directory that is positioned on the same level in directory hierarchy as the `java` and `res` folder.
- Second, you should pass path relative to the `assets` directory. So if your file is located directly under `assets` then the relative path is `"androidmodel.obj"`. Thus, creating input stream will look like this:

```
InputStreamReader(mContext?.getAssets()?.open("androidmodel.obj"))
```

But I strongly recommend you to check for non-null because if `mContext` is null - the issue will return.

```
mContext?.getAssets()?.open("androidmodel.obj")?.let { nonNullAsset ->
    InputStreamReader(nonNullAsset)
}
```

This part is crucial `?.let {` as it runs the `let` function only if the object is not null.

If there is no `assets` directory, just create it as a simple directory and it will be picked up by IDE automatically:

[image: main directory hierarchy]

#### Update

As the NPE still occurs the only reason left is the `null` value in `mContext` variable. Make sure it is initialized.

And after a little bit more digging, I can say that this was the issue from the beginning. Any attempt to pass the wrong path of a file to the `assets.open(fileName)` function will result in `FileNotFoundException`. Thus, even though the path you use is wrong you did not even reach the point of opening a file as the context is null.

Comment: I will just implement the let part, because it still is returning nullpointer. my assets folder is just like that, same level as those folder in main...

Comment: Something tells me that `mContext` is null. Try force unwrapping it as: `mContext!.assets.open("androidmodel.obj")`. Most likely you will get NPE but this time because your `mContext` is null.

Comment: I don't know if it's the best approach but, form your answer I added `Application()` to the class,  `override fun onCreate() { super.onCreate() mContext = applicationContext}` and    ` fun getContext(): Context? { return mContext  }`. on the load fun I added   `val mContext = getContext() val am = mContext!!.assets` so that this `InputStreamReader(am.open("androidmodel.obj"))` would compile. Still the same error...  But now it's kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException and points to val am = mContext!!.assets

Comment: Your context is still `null`. If you are able to upload your project to the GitHub and post the link here in comments (or update the answer) I'll check it out.

Comment: Sure, is your github JeneaVranceanu? It's private so I'd have to invite you, just checking if I got it right

Comment: Yes, here's the link: https://github.com/JeneaVranceanu